# How to upload, delete, create folders in AWS EC2

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, amazon-ec2

I have successfully created an EC2 instance in AWS Beanstalk and uploaded my folders and files using the 'application source bundle' method. The app works fine.

However, the file update method, although much faster than the source bundle method, is way too slow for the development back-and-forth testing method. Fine for batch testing but not for many small PHP scripting changes.

I have successfully set up my SFTP/SSH client and can access the /var/app/current/[app root name]/ folder and files.

However, using the SFTP/SSH client, I find that I cannot change permissions, create folders, or delete, overwrite, send or rename folders or files which I'd prefer to be able to do for fast checking. All I can do is stare at it or copy them to my SSH client! All I get are 'permission denied' pop-ups.

How can I enable these permissions and actions?